# How do I load my page in reactjs when a user clicks an email verification link?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have an email verification route coming from nodejs. And I would like to display a page from my reactjs showing email verified. Both the nodejs and reactjs are on different ports. When the user clicks the verification link sent to their email, the verified page in react should be loaded. How best can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Just make a request to your backend from the React app. In the verification email, you can provide user with a query token: `http://frontendlink.com/auth/email/verify?token=12345`. In `useEffect` make a request to `http://backendlink.com/api/v1/auth/email/verify?token=12345`, if the request succeeds: render a success component, if it fails: render an error component.

Comment: Thank you, this gave me the idea. I used params instead of query, it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

React app is running on a different port just for the development process, after you'll be done developing you'll build the app and get static files to put on your node server to serve, so currently put in the mail the react link (with port 3000) and afterward just remember to change it to the port

Answer (score 0):

You need pass a parameter from backend to react app. This parameter can be rendered in html body or url parameter something like a query string.
When your react app loads, it must look if this parameter exists. If is found, then you navigate in you react app to the page you want to show.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I actually passed :tokenId as a url parameter from the bank end. Would this work? The route link looks like this.www.mysite.com/confirm/:tokenId.

Comment: in your case you must pass a query string parameter that your react app will have access to read it. `www.mysite.com/confirm?token=${your-token-here} `